# How can I include a secondary hard drive in Windows 8 File History?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, backup, file-history

I've got a Ubuntu Server w/ Samba running on it (which is the backup destination), and a laptop with 2 hard disk drives. (128GB SSD and 1TB HDD).

I'm trying to setup File History on the second drive, as I use it for all of my documents and other important files.

File Transfer apparently only backed up my SSD, and ignored my secondary 1TB drive completely.

The 1TB HDD is so much more important than the SSD that I would even opt out of backing it up just so that I could backup my 1TB HDD.

Does anyone have any insights on how one can change the source drive to be backed up? I've looked for a good hour and can't find any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Solution**

The solution to this problem is to add the desired locations to your Libraries. In Windows Explorer, you can create new libraries or edit existing ones, and add the location you want backed up in the properties window for said library.

By default, Libraries are found under the Favorites section on the left sidebar in Explorer.

Once that's done, go to File History and ensure it's set to backup your libraries.

From that point on, things should be backed up automatically.